# A tautology that contains quantifier and logical connective.

Tags: logic, quantifiers

It might seem a stupid "question", but I need a logical explanation of it.

If $p(x)$ is a predicate and $q$ is a statement, then $(\forall x:p(x))\wedge q\iff \forall x:(p(x)\wedge q)$, and similarly we get if $\wedge$ and/or $\forall$ replaced by $\vee$ and $\exists$ respectively.

I've tried to name some statements in order to make a truth table to convince myself, but I'm unable to name some explicitly.

$$--------$$
**Example**: Prove that 
$$A\cap \left ( \bigcup_{\alpha \in \Lambda}B_{\alpha} \right )=\bigcup_{\alpha \in \Lambda}(A\cap B_{\alpha})$$
where $A$ is a set and $\{ B_{\alpha} \}_{\alpha\in\Lambda}$ is a family of sets. If I understood the logical explanation above then I would prove this way
\begin{align}
A\cap \left ( \bigcup_{\alpha \in \Lambda}B_{\alpha} \right )&=\left \{ x\mid x\in A \right \}\cap\left \{ x\mid \forall \alpha \in\Lambda:x\in B_{\alpha} \right \}\\
&=\left \{ x\mid \forall \alpha \in\Lambda:(x\in A)\wedge (x\in B_{\alpha}) \right \}\\
&=\left \{ x\mid \forall \alpha \in\Lambda:x\in A\cap B_{\alpha} \right \}\\
&=\bigcup_{\alpha \in \Lambda}(A\cap B_{\alpha}).
\end{align}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why is this so? $(∀x:p(x))∧q⟺∀x:(p(x)∧q)$

*Versa:* If $p(x)$ is true for any $x$, and $q$ is true (and $x$ is free in $q$), then both $p(x)$ and $q$ are true for any $x$.

*Vice versa:* If both $p(x)$ and $q$ are true for any $x$ (and $x$ is free in $q$), then $p(x)$ is true for any $x$ and $q$ is true.

$$(∀x:p(x))∧q⟺∀x:(p(x)∧q)$$

---

If $p(x)$ is true for any $x$, *or* $q$ is true (and $x$ is free in $q$), then either $p(x)$ or $q$ are true for any $x$.

*Vice versa:* If either $p(x)$ or $q$ are true for any $x$ (and $x$ is free in $q$), then either $p(x)$ is true for every $x$ , or $q$ is true.

$$(∀x:p(x))\vee q⟺∀x:(p(x)\vee q)$$

---

*Versa:* If $p(x)$ is true for *some* $x$, and $q$ is true (and $x$ is free in $q$), then both $p(x)$ and $q$ are true for some $x$.

*Vice versa:* If both $p(x)$ and $q$ are true for *some* $x$ (and $x$ is free in $q$), then $p(x)$ is true for some $x$ and $q$ is true.

$$(\exists x:p(x))∧q⟺\exists x:(p(x)∧q)$$

---

If $p(x)$ is true for some $x$, *or* $q$ is true (and $x$ is free in $q$), then either $p(x)$ or $q$ are true for some $x$.

*Vice versa:* If either $p(x)$ or $q$ are true for some $x$ (and $x$ is free in $q$), then either $p(x)$ is true for some $x$ , or $q$ is true.

$$(\exists x:p(x))\vee q⟺\exists x:(p(x)\vee q)$$

Answer (score 1):

Are you looking for example predicates? How about:

Let the domain be the set of U.S. Presidents.
Let $p(x)$ be "$x$ is male", and
$q$ be "Barack Obama is black."

Then $(\forall x :p(x)) \wedge q$ holds because every U.S. President is male, and also Barack Obama is black. The statement $\forall x: (p(x) \wedge q)$ is also true, because for each U.S. President, it is the case that that U.S. President is male *and* Barack Obama is black.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I am not looking for the example but I just want to know generally why it is true. Is there any way to show it using a truth table?

Answer (score 1):

"I've tried to name some statements in order to make a truth table to convince myself"

*But truth-tables aren't the appropriate apparatus here.*

The only wffs of quantified logic that can be shown to be valid using truth-tables are those wffs where (in a good sense) the quantifiers aren't relevant to the validity -- where we can systematically replace quantified bits like $\forall x Fx$ by simply $P$ and the wff is still valid.

For example, the wff $\forall xFx \to \forall xFx$ is valid because it is just like the wff $P \to P$, and both are instances of the tautologically valid form $\alpha \to \alpha$. You can show the validity of that form using a truth-table (that's what we mean when we say it is tautological) -- but *that's because it has nothing essentially to do with quantifiers*.

On the other hand although $\forall xFx \to \exists xFx$ is valid it isn't valid by the truth-table test, it isn't valid just because of the truth-functional connective it contains. It isn't an instance of truth-table-valid form such as $\alpha \to \alpha$ or of any other tautologically valid form. Rather it is valid in virtue of the meanings of the two quantifiers

The logically validity of $(\forall xFx \land Q) \equiv \forall x(Fx \land Q)$ is of the second kind. This is not the instance of a truth-table tautology but valid because of the meaning of the quantifiers. And because it isn't an instance of a truth-table tautology, you can't use truth-tables to prove its validity.

Answer (score 0):

does this help?
$$
\forall x \quad  p(x)
$$
may be envisaged as a conjunction
$$
\land_{x \in U} \quad p(x)
$$
where $U$ is the relevant universe

similarly
$$
\exists x \quad  p(x)
$$
may be envisaged as a conjunction
$$
\lor_{x \in U} \quad p(x)
$$